# VS2010 - How to change what the Solution Explorer displays

Tags: visual-studio-2010

I'm using Visual Studio 2010 and sometimes in some of my projects, for reasons that are unknown to me, the "folders" displayed in the Solution Explorer change and I can never seem to change them back unless I create a new project and copy the files over.

I want the solution explorer to display "Header Files", "Source Files" and "Resource Files" instead of just "Debug".

Here's an image of what I want it to display like when I create a new project:

http://www.jumbala.net/VS2010_SE_HeaderSource.png

Here's what it displays sometimes:

http://www.jumbala.net/VS2010_SE_Debug.png

I looked in the menus and I couldn't find anything to change it back.

**Edit:** Someone posted that I had "Show all files" checked in the second image, but he/she deleted his/her post. So yeah, that's why it wasn't working. I feel like an idiot for not noticing, but I thought that button and the one on the left (which is 'Properties') were mutually exclusive and so I had tried pressing 'properties' but not 'show all files'.

Thanks whoever posted the answer and deleted it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To fix this, just uncheck the "show all files" button that appears ticked in the second image.